# how to match column with other columns that have json

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-json

So the condition is I want to match if column EIF.value is equal to EF.possible_values json column "key" then display EF.possible_values json column "value". Mysql version is 8.0.33

This is the  EIF.value example data,,

```
"50010001"
"50010002"
```

This is the EF.possible_values json column example data,,

```
  [{"key": "50010001", "value": "MSG - BULK", "status": 1},
  {"key": "50010002", "value": "AJI NEX - BULK", "status": 1}]
```

The condition,,

```
if EIF.value == EF.possible_values json column "key" 
Then display EF.possible_values json column "value"
```

This is the query which i have not add the matching part,,

```
SELECT 
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(EF.possible_values, '$[*].value')) AS valuess
FROM 
  TAL.employee_expenses as EE
  JOIN TAL.expense_categories as ECAT on EE.expense_category_id = ECAT.id
  LEFT JOIN TAL.expense_groups as EXPGROUP on ECAT.expense_group_id = EXPGROUP.id
  LEFT JOIN TAL.employee_claims as EC on EC.id = EE.employee_claim_id
  LEFT JOIN TAL.expense_items as EI on EI.employee_expense_id = EE.id
  LEFT JOIN TAL.expense_item_fields as EIF on EIF.expense_item_id = EI.id
  LEFT JOIN TAL.expense_fields AS EF ON EF.id = EIF.expense_field_id
WHERE
  EE.employer_id = 502754
  AND EF.name = 'Profit Center'
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3